# Certificate management and use in rabbit mq auth backend

Tags: rabbitmq, ca, mutual-authentication, mtls, acme

How can we automate certificate management and its distribution with rabbitmq?
Is there any opensourced solution for creating self managed CA and certificate management to enable mutual authentication in Rabbit MQ